# How to automatically have dead Docker Swarm Manager replaced to have at least x manager running?

Tags: docker, high-availability, docker-swarm

How people detect and automate replacement of dead Swarm Manager?

That seems important considering: "If the swarm loses the quorum of managers, the swarm cannot perform management tasks."

Comment: AFAIK there's no built-in solution, so I would suggest you to look into monitoring tools like [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/). You would also need some kind of metrics collector (they are called "exporters" in the Prometheus context), e.g. like this one: https://github.com/bvis/docker-prometheus-swarm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement this with an external monitoring solution. It's not a built in capability of docker swarm mode.

Implementing this solution will be non-trivial. First, keep in mind when you promote a node, you are now giving it full administrative access over the swarm where a normal worker has none of that access, so make sure your security model is ok with this change. You also need to avoid cascade failures, where an overload of one manager causes it to fail, and automatically promoting other nodes causes them to immediately fail until there are no more workers as the existing workload is redistributed to fewer and fewer nodes. Lastly, when you add a new manager, you'll need to consider what to do with the reference to the currently failed manager. If it recovers, do you want it to continue where it left off, or do you want to have it completely removed from the swarm to reduce the number of nodes needed for quorum.

One last thing to note is when you lose quorum, nodes will continue to run the containers they have started. The only thing you lose is the ability to manage and make changes to that infrastructure. Therefore most places I've seen have 3 or 5 managers, depending on the level of fault tolerance needed, and often make the managers virtual so that if a failure occurs, the VM image can be easily restarted elsewhere in their environment.

Comment: This is definitely correct and effectively is the "burden" of distributed infrastructure in general, whether it is Swarm, etcd, consul, Kubernetes, or any number of highly available systems which require multi-node quorum to operate properly. This is why Docker created the [InfraKit](https://github.com/docker/infrakit) project for declarative state managed infrastructure. This alleviates the burden of creating your own framework to handle node management. I'm sure there are others, but InfraKit might be worth a look.

Comment: @PhilE I've been holding off recommending that one since I haven't had time to play with it in the lab, and it's still under very active development. That said, I don't know how I forgot to even mention it, thanks for the comment.